# How to test for a intermittant value Python MagicMock

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

Consider the following function

```
def sendRoute(self, msg):
    a = msg.a
    msg.a = "B"
    route.send(msg)
    msg.a = a

def test():
    msg = Message()
    msg.a = "A"
    route.send = MagicMock()
    print (str(route.send.mock_calls[0][1][0].a))
```

I want to write a test to verify that the msg.a sent by route.send is "B" but when I use MagicMock (for route.send) and check the mock_calls for the object it is of course updated to the "A" value again?

Does anyone know how to test for Value at the time of execution of route.send?